# Next-Previous button to work in loop using Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Currently "Previous" Button doesn't work in the first tab since it's not in the loop. How should I go about setting it so that when my visitors click on previous, it shows the last tab?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id="wheel-tab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#ocean" data-toggle="tab">Ocean</a></li>
        <li><a href="#air" data-toggle="tab">Air</a></li>
        <li><a href="#customs" data-toggle="tab">Customs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#transport" data-toggle="tab">Transport</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="ocean" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h2>Ocean</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="air" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h2>Air</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="customs" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h2>Customs</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="transport" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h2>Transport</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#" id="wheel-left"role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon icon-left">Prev</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" id="wheel-right" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon icon-right">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $tabs = $('#wheel-tab li');

$('#wheel-left').on('click', function () {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
});

$('#wheel-right').on('click', function () {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5vwb116q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check of length with respect to `prev` and `next` and if it is present just continue with the normal thing else, toggle the `last/first` tabs respectively. Take a look at solution below and also go through comments:

```
$('#wheel-left').on('click', function() {
    var prevLen = $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').length; //check if prev li is present
    if (prevLen)
        $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');//if yes then continue with normal tab switch
    else
        $tabs.filter('li:last').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');//else show the last tab
});

$('#wheel-right').on('click', function() {
    var nextLen = $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').length;//check if next li is present
    if (nextLen)
        $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');//if yes then continue with normal tab switch
    else
        $tabs.filter('li:first').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');//else show the first tab
});
```

## [`Updated Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/5vwb116q/4/)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

Using `:first` and `:last` test if its the last/first item in the list, if it is show the first/last tab

```
var $tabs = $('#wheel-tab li');

    $('#wheel-left').on('click', function () {
        if($('.active').is('#wheel-tab li:first')) {
            $('#wheel-tab li:last').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        } else {
        $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        }
    });

    $('#wheel-right').on('click', function () {
     if($('.active').is('#wheel-tab li:last')) {
            $('#wheel-tab li:first').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        } else {
        $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pc28q6wa/

or:

```
var $tabs = $('#wheel-tab li');
var first = $('#wheel-tab li:first');
var last = $('#wheel-tab li:last');

$('#wheel-left').on('click', function () {
    if($('.active').is(first)) {
        last.find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    } else {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    }
});

$('#wheel-right').on('click', function () {
 if($('.active').is(last)) {
       first.find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    } else {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I already got it working using Guruprasad's code :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code and it is perfectly working for me .Have a look at it.

```
$('#wheel-left').on('click', function () {

if($tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').is('li') > 0) {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');    
}
else{
    $tabs.last().tab('show');    
}
 });

 $('#wheel-right').on('click', function () {
   $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
 });
```

Thanks